# Force XWindows Authentication

Tags: x-windows, gdm

I start a process with init.d and want to be able to create GUI applications as child processes.

Because of the early start of this process, the environment variables DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY are not set.

I can just set DISPLAY to be :0.0, which works fine. However, I am having more trouble with the XAUTHORITY variable.

I could just set XAUTHORITY to point to the .XAuthority file in the users home directory - but it does not exist. Instead, when logged in normally to an X-Session, the XAUTHORITY variable is set to some file under /var/run/gdm/ and has a seemingly random flename.

As root, can I just generate a new cookie for myself?

Comment: Use `xauth add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generate a new cookie: the cookie is the "secret password" which the server was told when it started and which all clients need to know in order to connect.

I think you can get what you want with something like

```
DISPLAY=:0
XAUTHORITY=$(ps auxw | sed -ne "s|.*/[X].* $DISPLAY.*-auth \\([^ ]*\\).*|\\1|p")
export DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
...
```

This works by looking for the X server process trying to find the `-auth` argument that was passed to it, since that should be a file which contains the XAUTH settings.  Note that this file will usually (in my experience) be owned by root and other users can't read it, so if you want to then run an X application that doesn't run as root, you'll first need to copy this file (as root) elsewhere and change the owner of that copy (or more likely, you'll want to transfer the contents of this file to the user's `~/.Xauthority` file, using `xauth add` or `xauth merge`).

Another way to find the file where the magic cookie is stored is to look at the environment of some of the processes of the user that's logged in (e.g. the `gnome-shell` process).  E.g. with `ps` you should be able to find the process-id of the `gnome-shell` process (or some other user process which we expect to be running as X client), and then look in `/proc/<process-id>/environment` to find the value of its XAUTHORITY envvar.